# Which neutral atom-based quantum sensor is hardest to build/operate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, sensor

I am currently going through the presentation, "[Sensing with neutral atoms](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1257171)", by Grant Biedermann.

I understand that, according to the talk, there are a large number of different sensing setups including but not limited to the following:

1. Atomic fountain / Qubit fountain (Typical accuracy now better than one part in $10^{15}$)
2. Light-pulse atom interferometry (e.g. $^{87}$Rb, Cs, Na)
3. Single atom interferometry (Cs)
4. Quantum gas microscope ($^{87}$Rb)

I would like to understand which (could be beyond the options mentioned above) neutral atom-based quantum sensor suffers the most from the lack of the precision knowledge about the energy levels. According to the accepted response to another question I have asked [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9034/whats-the-point-of-doing-high-accuracy-spectroscopy-calculations/9054#9054), a $k$ order of improvement in precision of the energy level will reduce the number of measurement by same amount.

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to build for who? With what budget and for what purpose? At what level of accuracy? None of these are physics experiments that one would normally build at home but for some of the employees at NIST they are simply part of their daily jobs. One can probably also build a simple student experiment at most universities with a physics department and shop, but an actual precision setup would call for far larger effort and resources that could be tens, if not hundreds of times that of a simple student experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, atom interferometry does not suffer (/is currently not suffering) from precise knowledge of energy levels.

The laser light is typically (far-) detuned from any atomic transition anyway. The phase that is measured does not (usually) depend on the atomic structure.
Only one exception I can think of: The AC stark shift. But there are techniques to compensate for this without detailed knowledge of the precise transition frequency.

Also the quantum gas microscope is not limited at all by the knowledge of energy levels. This device is not even a "quantum sensor" in itself.